# AviFile - GetFrameOpen() problems

Tags: c#, video, video-streaming

Hi!

```
AviManager oldFile = new AviManager("C:\\Export.avi",true);
VideoStream oldStream = oldFile.GetVideoStream();
oldStream.GetFrameOpen();
```

On oldStream.GetFrameOpen() - error. Why?

```
getFrameObject = Avi.AVIStreamGetFrameOpen(StreamPointer, ref bih);
```

always return 0

Comment: getFrameObject = Avi.AVIStreamGetFrameOpen(StreamPointer, ref bih);

getFrameObject always == 0

Comment: Did you solve this error?